France Working Visa and Mental Health
I have an interview for a UK company (I have a British passport) to work as a seasonnaire/for a ski season. I'm pretty sure I'm going to get it.
Regarding the work visa, I know there is a medical element to it, I.e OFII medical check. From what I gather it's more about TB/yellow fever, etc. However, I'm on antidepressants.
Will having depression/being on medication affect the process and what is the medical like?

Many people, mostly Americans, have written online about their experience (also check the links and comments). Mental health might come up and you might get some advice on the French health system and the like but all this should remain confidential.
You're probably more concerned about the reasons that might lead OFII to refuse to issue the “certificat médical” you need to confirm your residence permit. Those are listed in the Arrêté du 11 janvier 2006 relatif à la visite médicale des étrangers autorisés à séjourner en France, namely:

Infectious disease covered by the International Health Regulations (the original 1951 list was plague, cholera, smallpox, typhus, and relapsing fever; the last version of the IHR doesn't have a fixed list and introduced a more flexible system but French law still refers to the old one)
Active tuberculosis
Mental health issues that make you a danger to others or to the “public order”
Any health issue that is obviously incompatible with the purpose of your stay

So unless your depression is so severe that you are unable to work, it shouldn't be an issue.
Only the first item in the list can make you permanently ineligible, for the last three the application is “put on hold” while you receive treatment.
